# php session doesn't work when the user move to 3rd page

Tags: php, session

A simple site on xampp to test php sessions :

- 1th page :  the user writes his/her name in a simple form (method post) and goes to 2nd page
- 2nd page : session works all right- the session echoes the user name from the form, and sends the user to 3rd page
- 3rd page : at the beggining of the the code `<?php session_start(); ?>`
  but it doesn't always work.

when i'm tring to `echo` the user name again at 2nd page, it always gives me the error:

> " Undefined variable: _session ... "

what can i do ? 
thanks :-)

Comment: PHP variable names are case sensitive. `$_session` is a COMPLETELY different variable than `$_SESSION`

Comment: The fact that you have a 3th page is puzzling enough.

Comment: thnks , i chaked it , its not the problem...